# Drawing Weather Data Graph with Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an exercise at University, where is asked to draw the graph using openGraphics, canvas...

I've almost reached the finish line. The only thing doesn't work correctly, is that rectangles, which play role of columns goes down instead of going up.

It looks like that :
[image]

But should look like that :

[image]

Code :

```
var canvas;
canvas = openGraphics();

canvas.setFont("TIMES", "13px", Font.BOLD);
canvas.drawString("Weather Data: Bradford 2015", 5, 10);
canvas.drawString("Sunshine (in hours)", 5, 30);
canvas.setFont("TIMES", "12px", Font.PLAIN);

var i = 0;
var k = 0;
var month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
while(i < 12) {
var hours = prompt("Type amount of sunshine hours for " + month[k]);

canvas.setColor("pink");
canvas.fillRect(20+30*i, 280, 30, hours);
canvas.setColor("black");
canvas.drawRect(20+30*i, 280, 30, hours);


i += 1;
k += 1;

}

canvas.setStroke("3");
canvas.drawLine(20, 60, 20, 280);
canvas.drawLine(20, 280, 380, 280);

canvas.setFont("TIMES", "13px", Font.BOLD);
canvas.drawString("0", 5, 270);
canvas.drawString("45", 5, 225);
canvas.drawString("90", 5, 180);
canvas.drawString("135", 0, 135);
canvas.drawString("180", 0, 90);
canvas.drawString("225", 0, 55);
canvas.drawString("J", 35, 285);
canvas.drawString("F", 65, 285);
canvas.drawString("M", 95, 285);
canvas.drawString("A", 125, 285);
canvas.drawString("M", 155, 285);
canvas.drawString("J", 185, 285);
canvas.drawString("J", 215, 285);
canvas.drawString("A", 245, 285);
canvas.drawString("S", 275, 285);
canvas.drawString("O", 305, 285);
canvas.drawString("N", 335, 285);
canvas.drawString("D", 365, 285);


canvas.paint();
```

Comment: Amazing, it works!
Thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rectangles are going to be drawn starting from a point representing their top left corner. That point is the first 2 arguments of the `canvas.fillRect`.

So I see: `canvas.fillRect(20+30*i, 280, 30, hours);`, where your starting y coordinate is the same for each rectangle (280). That means it's going to draw down `hours` amount from 280. So yes, that would make all the rectangles go down and look reversed from what you intend.

Try starting from `280-hours` in the second argument.

So: `canvas.fillRect(20+30*i, 280-hours, 30, hours);`